# Magento : Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Tabs.php on line 60

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

On Product detail page i got Fatal error i don't know why this error coming. what should i do to fix it. Every time got this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Tabs.php on line 60

thanks

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: thanks for reply , i don't do the code but i got an issue and fixed it.